# Is the ".get()" function considered as a request?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Im using parse cloud code and I need to use get() function in a recursive metohd.

Considering the pricing plan of Parse, which based on number of requests to the server, I need to check if every time I'm using the get method, its calculated as a individual request.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("User")
    query.limit(1000);
    query.find(
        {
            success: function (results) 
             for (var j = 0 ; j < results.length ; j++)
                {
                  if(results[j].get("username").indexOf(shortNumberArray[i]) > - 1)
                       {
                           break;
                       }
                }
        });
```

if it is considered as individual request, are there any alternatives for this method?

Comment: Are you asking if an HTTP request is counted as HTTP request at some service? Think again about your question.

Comment: Ok. is there any other way to get the "username" column? Because if I understand you right, I'm calling a lots of HTTP requests here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, getting a property on a Parse object does not make an HTTP request. If the property is a Pointer to another object and you need a property on that object, then use the [Parse.Query.include()](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#include) method to include the full object on your query.

To illustrate, make this the first line in your success function:

```
console.log(results);
```

**Update**: If the username is all you're after, then use `pluck` in [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) (or [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck)):

```
_ = require('underscore');

...
    success: function (results) {
        usernamesArray = _.pluck(results, 'username');
```

Comment: Thank you. how can I get array with only "username" that inside the "User" table?